# Why was the Wakandan attack so weak?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Wakanda, which is sitting on a rich reserve of Vibranium, is depicted as a more advanced civilization then the rest of the world in *Black Panther*.

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, during the battle of Wakanda with the Black Order, we see that they have one hell of a defense with a dome shaped energy shield, nearly impenetrable. But when the shield does get penetrated, the only weapons Wakandan's use are spears that also shoot energy blasters which are not very efficient attack weapons. The War Machine single-handedly does more damage than possibly all Wakandans.

Why was their attack so weak? Why didn't they use tanks & stuff or have aerial backup like helicopters? Why was their attack strategy focused on hand to hand combat only despite having a technologically advanced civilization?

Comment: I watched IW before BP and was really confused by this the whole time I watched the latter.  I was like... weren't they fighting with spears before?  Why not use their ridiculous science tech?

Comment: The shield wasn't penetrated, they opened it intentionally, as a really smart tactical play.  They observed the enemy starting to circumnavigate the shield looking for vulnerabilities, and they knew the enemy would find one.  Rather than have the shield fail on the enemy's terms, they failed it on their own terms, canalizing the enemy into one narrow gap.  Makes me wonder which war college T'Challa attended, Annapolis? West Point?

Comment: @Harper kinda like Hot gates ;)

Answer (score 17):

> Why was their attack so weak? Why didn't they use tanks & stuff or have aerial backup like helicopters? Why was their attack strategy focused on hand to hand combat only despite having a technologically advanced civilization?

### It's most likely the case that Wakanda has never had to defend themselves on such a large scale before.

Since Wakanda has always been hidden from the rest of the world, then, historically speaking, there'd be no reason for them to have such large artillery. Instead, Wakanda is much more accustomed to dealing with internal battles between tribes -- exclusively within Wakanda -- and their only measurements against the outside world has been their force-field bubble defense.

At the same time, IIRC, Wakanda didn't have much time to prepare for Thanos's attack either, so, it's not like they could have build such large/powerful weapons in preparation. IMO, Wakanda seemed lucky enough to get everyone together in one place, and to be fighting as a single People.

Comment: Also, at least some of the Dragonflies (fighters) and battle-rhinos were destroyed during the fighting in Black Panther and apparently not replaced. It's possible that Wakanda doesn't have a large industrial infrastructure to speedily produce more high-tech weapons systems.

Comment: When they opened their borders to the rest of the world, what were they expecting would come their way, the Olympics or a Starbucks? I am undecided on your argument so far.

Comment: @KharoBangdo What does Starbucks/Olympics have to do with the ability to fight a war?

Comment: @Charles I was making a reference to the movie dialogue. What I meant was Wakanda was coming out of the shadow & exposing themselves as a vibranium rich nation. Lots of nation would want to seek war directly or indirectly to mine that vibranium. Also when Killmonger wanted to arm black folks of the world with weapons, were those weapons just spears?

Comment: All they had was spears & shield. What were they expecting? Meeting Dothraki in an open field?

Comment: @KharoBangdo Yes, I remember Okoye making that off the cuff ***joke*** to T'Challa, just before the fights begins. But, I'm still having a difficult time understanding what aspect of my response you disagree with..

Comment: @Charles I don't disagree, I am undecided between agree & disagree